# Java remote debugging - how can I keep debugger listening?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to remote debug a Java CLI program with the debugger listening for connections.

This works fine for the first invocation, but the debugger stops listening after the CLI program disconnects. I want the debugger to keep listening since multiple CLI invocations will be made (in sequence, not in parallel) and only one of these will trigger the breakpoint I've set.

Here's my client debug config:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=5005,suspend=y
```

Is it possible to keep the debugger listening?

Comment: Well, if  "CLI program disconnects" means JVM stop, there is no easy way to achieve what you want.

Comment: @IgorDiy Yes the JVM running the CLI exits and disconnects from the listening debugger. I've thought about reversing the client/server relationship and have the CLI jvm do the listening (with server=y,suspend=y) but that would require connecting the debugger on each invocation. Not optimal though in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Well since your CLI program terminates, debugger also stops. If you still want to continue debugger session for multiple runs of CLI program, then you can try as below,

Write a wrapper program from which you invoke your CLI program multiple times and debug the wrapper program instead of your CLI program.

Something like this,

```
public class Wrapper {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        YourCLIProgram yp = new YourCLIProgram();
        // First Invocation
        String[] arg1 = { }; // Arguments required for your CLI program
        yp.main(arg1);
        // Second Invocation
        String[] arg2 = { }; // Arguments required for your CLI program
        yp.main(arg2);
        // Third Invocation
        String[] arg3 = { }; // Arguments required for your CLI program
        yp.main(arg3);
        // Fourth Invocation
        String[] arg4 = { }; // Arguments required for your CLI program
        yp.main(arg4);

    }
}
```

I hope it works.

Comment: In my case this wasn't an option as I was trying to debug while automated system tests were running, but given the right context I can see how this would be a valid strategy.

Comment: Somehow write a wrapper program and call your automated tests and then debug the wrapper program. I dont know how your automated tests are written and triggered. If you are running some command to trigger your tests, then do exec(<your command>) in wrapper program.

Answer (score 1):

It depends also what you are trying to achieve. 
If you want to check what parameters are passed to your CLI you can just log them to the file or save any information that you need in DB (or file as well).

Comment: This is essentially what I did in the end; I logged which CLI arguments caused the crash and then added a wrapper to the CLI that applied the java debug options when those arguments were used. Then I was able to run the test automation and wait for the debugger to hit the breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

In [JPDA](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/architecture.html) by specification [transport service](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/architecture.html) could support or not multiple connections.
For example, in Eclipse it [doesn't](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.debug/blob/master/org.eclipse.jdt.debug/jdi/org/eclipse/jdi/internal/connect/SocketTransportService.java). I suppose the same for IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

When setting up your run configuration, did you select the "Listen" Debugger mode?  The command line arguments you show look like the normal "Attach" settings, whereas the arguments for "Listen" look like this:
`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,address=yourhost.yourdomain:5005, suspend=y,onthrow=<FQ exception class name>,onuncaught=<y/n>`  (Specifically, your arguments are missing the address for the application - your CLI program - to connect to IDEA at on start-up.)

I read a post that suggests the "onthrow" argument may not be necessary for general debugging, but I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I had the debugger listening and the process to be debugged using "server=n".

Answer (score 0):

Try with suspend=n:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

On my local app (tomcat web app), even though I run on JDK8, I still use the older way of doing it and it works fine (another thing you could try):

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
```

Comment: Tried both suspend=y and suspend=n before posting but it didn't helo.